# Troubleshoot DBMail in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, troubleshooting

On a SQL Server 2005 machine, I have DBMail setup and correctly configured. I am able to use "Notify Operator" and `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` to queue emails.

But the problem is the queued mails never go through. I see 10 emails in the queue when I query

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_unsentitems
```

But if I **restart** the SQL Server service, all mails go through and I receive emails in my inbox.

So far this is the only pattern I could find.

So my question is: is there a way to troubleshoot DBmail? I read some steps on MSDN, but they are not of much help. Any URLs to articles that could help are much appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this guide:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188663.aspx (You might want to check "Troubleshooting Database Mail: Mail queued, not delivered" section).

Otherwise, check the Event Viewer and post here the errors you find.